# Поиск по динамически изменяемому словарю

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Имеется словарь вида

```
world = {'city':{'Moscow':{'person':{'Name': 'Max', 'LastName': 'Sidorov'}, 'person1':{'Name': 'Nikita', 'LastName': 'Petrov'}}, 'London':{'person':{'Name': 'John', 'LastName': 'Stones'}, 'person1':{'Name': 'Wayne', 'LastName': 'Rooney'}}}}
```

Нужно, чтобы при вводе имени, выводился словарь содержащий это имя.
**Если же данное имя отсутствует, необходимо, чтобы выдавалось значение None, 0, или ошибка.**
На данный момент, при вводе несуществующего имени выводится пустота.

Использую данный код:

```
def get_all_dicts(seq_or_mapping, predicate):
if hasattr(seq_or_mapping, 'values'):
    if predicate(seq_or_mapping):
       yield seq_or_mapping
    values = seq_or_mapping.values()
else:
    values = seq_or_mapping

for value in values:
    if isinstance(value, (dict, list)):
        yield from get_all_dicts(value, predicate)

for d in get_all_dicts(world, lambda d: d.get('Name') == 'Andrey'):
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
world = {
    'city': {
        'Moscow': {
            'person': {
                'Name': 'Max',
                'LastName': 'Sidorov'
            },
            'person1': {
                'Name': 'Nikita',
                'LastName': 'Petrov'
            }
        },
        'London': {
            'person': {
                'Name': 'John',
                'LastName': 'Stones'
            },
            'person1': {
                'Name': 'Wayne',
                'LastName': 'Rooney'
            }
        }
    }
}

def find_name(data, name):
    for city in data:
        for key in data[city]:
            pack = data[city][key]
            if pack['Name'] == name:
                return pack
    # значение None, 0, или ошибка
    return None

print(find_name(world['city'], 'John'))  # {'Name': 'John', 'LastName': 'Stones'}
print(find_name(world['city'], 'Anton'))  # None
```